# Xamarin.Forms: Title in TableSection in TableView not displaying on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

I am using TableView in my application. The title under the TableSection is displayed on iOS but doesn't show up on Android. How can I fix that?

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="true" BackgroundColor="#E7E7E7">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Child Info"> 
                <ViewCell x:Name="Profile">
                    <StackLayout 
                        BackgroundColor="White" 
                        HeightRequest="40" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                        Padding="10">

                            <Label 
                                Text="Child Profile" 
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                            <Image 
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsError}" 
                                Source="ic_provider_error" 
                                WidthRequest="30" 
                                HeightRequest="30" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Button 
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                TextColor="Blue" 
                                x:Name="profileSync" 
                                Text="Sync" 
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                                Clicked="OnChildProfileClicked" 
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsProgress, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}" />                            
                                <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding Content}" 
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsProgress}" />                         
                    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean that title "Child Info" is not shown on Android? I tested on emulator with Android 6.0, it shows well. Could you please provide more information like your Xamarin.Forms version, the target version of your android project and your emulator?

Comment: I use samsung galaxy s4 to test. Yes the child info not showing.

Comment: The same is happening to me on an Samsung Galaxy Tab E with Android 4.4.4. App target is Android 6.0 Min Version 4.0.3, compiled against 6.0. XF used is 2.3.3.193. VS2017 CE with Xamarin 4.3.0.784 and Xamarin.Android 7.1.0.41 installed. Developing on an Win 8 machine.